# Can an AppX installer for an application remove an older installation of the application installed using an MSI?

Tags: c#, installation, windows-store-apps, appx

I have installed my Hello World application using an MSI that I created for it. I've since converted the MSI installer to an AppX installer. Is it possible for the AppX installer to detect an existing installation of my Hello World application installed by the MSI installer and remove it, much as a standard MSI upgrade installation would?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I try to sideload one app in local machine twice， and  I find when you sideload this app for the second time, the Appx installer can detect an existing app and remove the previous installation.

But it may not remind you that this app has been installed, and it doesn't also ask you that you wan to remove this app to reinstall or not, it just removes this app and reinstall app.

**Update**：I think **it is impossible for the Appx installer to detect an existing installation of your application installed by the MSI installer and remove it**. I install appx and there is no any detection information , and it will not remove the application installed by MSI installer

Comment: Yes, It is possible when you install same version of appx twice or msi twice.I need to detect an MSI while installing appx

Comment: @Visnu, I think it is impossible for the Appx installer to detect an existing installation of your application installed by the MSI installer and remove it. I install appx and there is no any detection information , and it will not remove the application installed by MSI installer.

Comment: Is it efficient? I have already have the same application as MSI.once i downloaded from the store i will going to use only that application and the MSI is going to dump my memory space.Is there any way to overcome this problem?